# Can I install Homebrew without sudo privileges?

Tags: macos, sudo, homebrew

Homebrew nicely allows package installations without sudo privileges, but it seems that I need admin privileges to install Homebrew itself.

I'd like to install Homebrew in a Mac environment where I don't have sudo or admin privileges. Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible: https://superuser.com/a/1603383/691810

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In case somebody is still looking for this in 2020 and beyond, yes, this is possible without root privileges:

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

The above allows you to install homebrew anywhere. Make sure that you add homebrew/bin to your $PATH.

More information about this alternative installation method is available in [Brew's installation instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere-unsupported).

Comment: Maybe this should be the top answer?

Comment: After settings, a `brew update` is most likely necessary to ensure freshness. I would also recommend this one---it just works.

Comment: I tried this, it works very well, simple & quick. Thanks

Comment: Looks like people are having more success with this answer and appears to be a new way to solve the problem, so I accepted it

Comment: This works on Big Sur, but only after I do `brew update-reset` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840631/573389

Comment: I live in beyond times after 2020, and this still works great. Saved my butt since work has our laptop fairly well locked down, but I can install the development tools I need with this trick.

Comment: Worked great on mac os ventura on apple silicon M2.

Answer (score 25):

Yes.

I modified the install script to not use `sudo` and to use a directory of your choice. https://gist.github.com/skyl/36563a5be809e54dc139

Download that, set `YOUR_HOME` in the script to the absolute path. `chmod +x` the script. Create the `YOUR_HOME/usr/local` directory. Then, execute the script.

```
./install.rb
```

In `.bash_profile`, I set (I'm not positive this is important, pretty sure):

```
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/The/path/to/YOUR_HOME/usr/local
```

Now, I can:

```
brew install wget
```

Make sure the `bin` directory, `YOUR_HOME` + `/usr/local/bin` is on your `$PATH`.

```
which wget
```

Comment: In the install script I had to add `#{YOUR_HOME}` prefix to the `HOMEBREW_CACHE` variable as well. That, and because the system admin already had homebrew installed, I had to add `export PATH=/path/to/home/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to `.bash_profile` as well. But with all that, it seems to work great.

Comment: Just went through the process again, and I just wanted to mention you also have to make a `usr` directory in your home directory before the script will run. Additionally, when you add `#{YOUR_HOME}` to the `HOMEBREW_CACHE` variable, it seems you need to change the single quotes to double quotes for it to work. So there are a few steps, but it's definitely worth it to get the power of Homebrew.

Comment: @golmschenk double quotes are required for ruby's string formatting to kick in, I believe.

Comment: That's a nice adjustment.  You really ought to submit a pull request to the home-brew project.

Comment: I tried this from a non-admin account on macOS Sierra (10.12.3) and it didn't work because it needed to do a `chgrp admin /usr/local`, and a non-admin account isn't a member of the admin group, so it can't change anything to that group. It would be great if this could be made to work for a normal non-admin account (not just for admin accounts that have for some strange reason been locked out of sudo).

Comment: I left the chgrp commands in and had no issues. In Mojave, and totally not an administrator. Here's a fork I recommend most people use: https://gist.github.com/devinrhode2/a37f9a05656fef604332779ec6e5f0b4
Disclaimer: I barely know ruby, but just plucked a few seemingly good bits from various people's forks. Worked fine for me.

Comment: Only thing I can't do is change my default shell to the brew-installed one. Otherwise, everything works!! (Instead I just uninstall zsh and re-ran chsh -s $(which zsh), which is the default-install /bin/zsh on mojave)

Comment: For homebrew cask users, you'll want to add this to your ~/.profile: `export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=~/Users/devinrhode3/Applications --fontdir=/Users/devinrhode3/Library/Fonts"`

Comment: I used the linked `install.rb` again successfully on catalina :)

Answer (score 17):

No.. Unless you do significant surgery.

The reason is that Homebrew strongly insists on installing packages into `/usr/local`.  In fact, even if you forced it to install somewhere else, you are likely to break dependencies when you use `brew install` to install packages.  Most if not all of these packages are pre-compiled and linked expecting to live in `/usr/local`.

The reason for this insistence is that `/usr/local` is precisely where POSIX recommends that stuff like this gets installed.  In order to create `/usr/local` Homebrew needs temporary admin credentials to create the directory and assign ownership.

This, in turn, is what allows you to install anything else without elevating credentials.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed my question. I know how & where it installs packages, but I want to install _Homebrew_ without admin or sudo.

Comment: I didn't miss your question.  The answer was "No".. I just said "Yes" accidentally.  You cannot easily do what you are asking and even if you forced it by editing the Homebrew installer to put things into a branch off of your home directory, more than likely lots of brews would fail after installation.

Comment: okay, thanks. I was confused by the previous "Yes".

Comment: This is just wrong, or at least you definition of "significant surgery" is very different then mine. I've been running `brew` with a prefix set to my home directory for 5 plus years and I've encounter 1 or 2 broken packages in that time.

Comment: However, also there is also this, which is hard to get around: Error: You have not agreed to the Xcode license. Please resolve this by running: sudo xcodebuild -license accept

Comment: @Albert I was recently checking the git version installed by default on mojave, I literally just typed "git" and hit enter, and I was able to get a prompt to install xcode cli tools, seems to have worked fine without admin privileges. (10.14.6)

Answer (score 2):

To install **homebrew without sudo**.

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
echo 'export PATH="/path/to/cloned_folder/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**Restart terminal** and run

```
brew --version
```

Comment: This still requires sudo access

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The brew system appears bootstrappable and can be installed in one own's home directory.  According to a comment by @Adrian, this will take much longer because each package will be built from its source code.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=~/homebrew
# export HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1
mkdir -p "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"
curl -fsSLk https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"

ls -laR "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"

export PATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin:${PATH}"
type -a brew

type -a openssl || :
openssl version -a || :

type -a curl || :
curl -V || :

# Fails to lock a .git/config file.
##brew analytics off

# No "brew update" until installing the proper openssl and a curl that uses it.
# brew update

# brew remove openssl || :
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl

# brew remove curl || :
brew install --with-openssl curl
brew link --force curl || :
curl -V

ls -la "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt"
ls -la "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin"
ls -laLR "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/curl/"
```

Comment: like 10x less code than the ruby version... but partly ruby has to deal with a lot of ceremony by not being a bash script.. @eel have you run into any issues with this installation?

Comment: I used this script only to get my homebrew going.  (A brew upgrade needs a trick with `brew update-reset`. https://gist.github.com/ilatypov/f197cd65941063e2df828122c7de0c52 ).

Comment: What do you mean "only get my homebrew going"? Are you able to get a successful homebrew setup going with this script? Install command line things like git, zsh, etc? I ended up using a tweaked version of Skyl's ruby script above, but, I am curious if this would have worked too.

Comment: Wow `brew install openssl` is painfully slow on my MBP :(

Comment: Updated openssl and now curl, and getting "Error: invalid option: --with-openssl" https://gist.github.com/devinrhode2/832288a0ef15d6e4e4dfc3e4a341bcbe

Comment: @DevinGRhode All core Homebrew formulae no longer support options like `--with-openssl`. Also, if you install Homebrew outside the official root, all your installs are likely to build from source, rather than using prebuilt binaries, so yeah, it'll be painfully slow.

Comment: I have no idea how you ensure curl is using the latest openssl.. Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: Answer still has "brew install --with-openssl curl" - @eelghEEz @Adrian how do I ensure `curl` is using the brew-installed openssl?

Comment: @DevinGRhode As of this writing, the `curl-openssl` formula no longer exists, and `brew install curl` installs the OpenSSL-enabled curl.

Answer (score 1):

Brew moved their git repo

```
git clone git@github.com:Homebrew/brew.git
echo 'export PATH="/path/to/cloned_folder/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: By 'the above' do you mean [Astik Anand's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1463605/288259)? It won't always be 'above' your answer. If something in their answer should be changed, edit it yourself.

Comment: Permission was denied

Comment: @pwaterz I have edited the other answer - would you want to delete this to clean things up?

Comment: No, because I don't credit for the answer then

Answer (score 0):

The following script shows a way to install brew without root. Please do `export` environment variables `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` & `PATH` in your `~/.zshrc` after installation to ensure the package will placed at a expected directory

## download

```bsh
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew
mkdir ~/usr/local
# installed packaged directory
echo "export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=~/usr/local" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/homebrew/bin:HOMEBREW_PREFIX/bin" >> ~/.zshrc
```

## update brew

```
brew update
# if error
brew update-reset
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).